# How will Hamiltonian Operator $H = q\vec{E}\cdot \vec{r}$ be affected by rotational operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, parity

I have a question about how will Hamiltonian Operator H = qE.r be affected by rotational operator. Not sure where to start and what happens if the direction of time is reversed ( t -> -t(T) )

Answer (score 1):

Without losing generality set $\vec{E}=E \hat{z}$ thus your term became $H=q E z$. Now computing $[H,L_i]$ you can see that only $[H,L_z]=0$ and so don't have a full $SO(3)$ symmetry but only an $SO(2)$ symmetry, this because you have the same physics rotating your system along the electric field axes.

Comment: surely a *scalar* product is rotationally invariant…